# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)

Tags: python, opencv

Código abaixo:

```
import cv2

imagemCarregada = cv2.imread("exemplo.jpg", 0)

cv2.imshow("imagem", imagemCarregada)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Erro apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro significa que você está carregando uma imagem vazia. Como especificado no erro, a imagem deve ter um ***width > 0*** e um ***height > 0***.

Aqui, consegui abrir uma imagem sem problemas com exatamente o mesmo código.

Possíveis causas do erro:

- A imagem não existe no diretório. Vale verifica novamente e tentar
  algo como: `cv2.imread("C:\\path\\to\\image.png")` ou
  `cv2.imread("C:/path/to/image.png"));`
- A extensão da imagem pode está errada. Lembre-se, **.jpg** é
  diferente de **.jpeg**
- Você pode não ter diretos para acessar a pasta da imagem.

Comment: Complementando o que o Guilherme disse sobre o caminho da imagem, vale ressaltar que quando você usa o caminho relativo para se referir a um arquivo, o python irá iniciar a procura baseando-se no diretorio definido em PYTHONPATH, uma variavel de ambiente com o diretorio local atribuida quando se chama o interpretador. Então pelo seu traceback, a imagem que você carrega deveria estar no Desktop.

Mas por organização, crie diretorios pros seus projetos e coloque tudo de possível referente a eles lá. Chamando o comando python sempre a partir da raiz deles.